# How to fix text with image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm doing my online portfolio website and I have a responsive problem (i always have responsive problems, hate this thing).

This is what I want my website to look like in all of screens resolutions:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/0W3k3Y0C3L2O2m2J2P1I/resolution2.jpg

The problem is, as you may know, when I code this in html even with Bootstrap, the the big text (designer, no matter what) covers me in the right, depending on the screen size.

How can I "fix" the text in the image so that no matter the screen size the text always stays in the same place of the image?

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` tags do not have an option to add text on it.

You can use images as background and add text. You can use `<div>` tags to server this purpose. Something like below:

```
<div class="imageContainer">Some Text</div>
```

use the css background-image property to show the image

```
.imageContainer {

       background-image: url(locationoftheimage);
 }
```

For smaller area's you can just make the image as link, if you want. For example your menu has links such as Home, About etc.

Make a small [image like this](http://prntscr.com/6c0g6t)

Code would be like this:

```
<a href="home"><img src ="url_of_Image"></a>
```

Comment: yes, this is what i did. I made a container with the background image and this text inside the container. But since the text and the image are separate things, depending on the screen size the text stays on top of me in the image.

Comment: something similar to this problem: 
right:http://cl.ly/image/0H0l231e002E
wrong: http://cl.ly/image/0A1x392N0I2E

Comment: You should probably put all your code in the question for better understanding

Comment: Here's my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uv3yw2eh/. All i really want is my website to look like this in all screen sizes: https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/1X1y3L0x3O0L2V3m360A/me.jpg